# Curl Exception 7 PHP and Guzzle with Elasticsearch

Tags: php, curl, elasticsearch

I am trying to index documents using the php client for elastic search which uses Guzzle. After compiling my php script I am getting an error that says Internal Server Error, code 500. After doing some research this seems to be an issue with connecting to a server but the strange part is that everything I'm trying to do is set up on the same machine. My instance of Elasticsearch, my documents I'm trying to index, and my php scripts are all saved and running on the same machine. This is my PHP Script:

```
<?php
require '/home/aharmon/vendor/autoload.php';

$client = new Elasticsearch\Client();

$root = realpath('/home/aharmon/elkdata/for_elk_test_2014_11_24/Agencies');

$iter = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($root, RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS),
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST,
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::CATCH_GET_CHILD);

$paths = array($root);
foreach ($iter as $path => $dir) {
if ($dir -> isDir()) {
    $paths[] = $path;
    }
}

//Create the index and mappings
$mapping['index'] = 'rvuehistoricaldocuments2009-2013'; //mapping code
$mapping['body'] = array (
'mappings' => array (
    'documents' => array (
        '_source' => array (
            'enabled' => true
        ),
        'properties' => array(
            'doc_name' => array(
                'type' => 'string',
                'analyzer' => 'standard'
            ),
            'description' => array(
                'type' => 'string'
            )
        )
    )
)
);






//Now index the documents
for ($i = 0; $i <= 10000; $i++) {
    $params ['body'] [] = array(
    'index' => array(
        '_id' => $i
        )
    );

    $params ['body'] [] = array(
    'type' => 'documents',
    'body' => array(
        'foo' => 'bar'//Document body goes here

        )
    );


//Every 1000 documents stop and send the bulk request.

if($i % 1000) {
    $responses = $client->bulk($params);

// erase the old bulk request
$params = array();

// unset the bulk response when you are done to save memory
unset($responses);
}
}

$client ->indices()->create($mapping)
?>
```

If anyone has seen this before or has an inclination as to what the issue the help would be greatly appreciated. I had a similar issue before when I tried to set up SSH but I got the firewall all configured and got SSH working so I'm not sure why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

check  this link it is ok for me :
http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/php-api/current/_index_operations.html#_put_mappings_api

```html
<?php
// Set the index and type
$params['index'] = 'my_index';
$params['type']  = 'my_type2';

// Adding a new type to an existing index
$myTypeMapping2 = array(
    '_source' => array(
        'enabled' => true
    ),
    'properties' => array(
        'first_name' => array(
            'type' => 'string',
            'analyzer' => 'standard'
        ),
        'age' => array(
            'type' => 'integer'
        )
    )
);
$params['body']['my_type2'] = $myTypeMapping2;

// Update the index mapping
$client->indices()->putMapping($params);
```